Buttons Frozen After Page Navigation
I have a Group Of Ejs Pages Rendered like this in the app/index.js:

app.get('/Pages/Inventory/:pageNumber', async (req, res) => {
    const pageNumber = parseInt(req.params.pageNumber);
    const pageSize = 20; 

    try {
        const books = await BookInventory.getInventory(pageNumber, pageSize);
        res.render('BookInventory', { books, pageNumber });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error retrieving inventory:', error);
        res.status(500).send('An error occurred.');
    }
});


The Page:

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Book Inventory</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../Styles/BookInventory.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../Styles/css/all.css">
        <link rel="icon" href="../../Images/Seal.ico">
        <script src="../../Scripts/BookInventory.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        
        <div class="Wrapper">
            
            <div class="Side-Bar">

                <div class="Side-Bar-Wrapper">

                    <div class="Side-Bar-Label">
                        <p>
                           Book Inventory
                        </p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="Side-Bar-Logo">
                        <img src="../../Images/SchoolLogo.png" width="180px" height="180px">
                    </div>

                    <div class="Side-Bar-Nav">

                        <div class="Side-Bar-Navigator" id="Organizations">
                            <div class="Side-Bar-Navigator-Icon">
                                <i class="fa-solid fa-sitemap"></i>
                                 <!--Icon Goes Here-->
                            </div>
                            <p>
                                User Organization
                            </p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="Side-Bar-Navigator" id="Inventory">
                            <div class="Side-Bar-Navigator-Icon">
                                <i class="fa-solid fa-book"></i>
                                 <!--Icon Goes Here-->
                            </div>
                            <p>
                               Book Inventory
                            </p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="Side-Bar-Navigator" id="Archives">
                            <div class="Side-Bar-Navigator-Icon">
                                <i class="fa-solid fa-box-archive"></i>
                                 <!--Icon Goes Here-->
                            </div>
                            <p>
                               Archives
                            </p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="Side-Bar-Navigator" id="Home">
                            <div class="Side-Bar-Navigator-Icon">
                                <i class="fa-solid fa-house"></i>
                                 <!--Icon Goes Here-->
                            </div>
                            <p>
                               Home
                            </p>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="Maincontent">

                <div class="Maincontent-Wrapper">

                    <div class="Top-Controls">
                        <div class="Search-Bar">
                            <input id="InventorySearch" class="Search-Input" type="text" placeholder="Search Inventory">
                            <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i>
                        </div>
                        <button class="AddBTN" id="Add-User">Add Book</button>
                    </div>

                    <!--For Each Book-->
                    <% books.forEach(book => { %>
                        <div class="Book-Entry" id="<%= book.BookID %>">
                            <div class="Cover">
                                <img src="../<%= book.BookCover %>" class="Entry-Cover">
                            </div>
                            <div class="Info-Block">
                                <span class="Title-Span">
                                    <h1 class="Book-Title"><%= book.BookTitle %></h1>
                                    <button class="Editing-Btn" id="Edit-Title"><i class="fa-solid fa-pen"></i></button>
                                </span>
                                <h2 class="Book-ID"># <%= book.BookID %></h2>
                                <div class="Author-Container">
                                    <h3>Author :</h3>
                                    <p class="Author">
                                        <span class="Book-Author"><%= book.BookAuthor %></span>
                                    </p>
                    
                                    <button class="Editing-Btn" id="Edit-Author">
                                        <i class="fa-solid fa-pen"></i>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="Buttons">
                                    <button class="ArchiveBtn" id="Archive-Book">Archive<i class="fa-solid fa-box-archive"></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <% }); %>

                    <div class="Pagination">
                        <div class="Pagination-Controls" data-pageNumber="1">
                            <button id="Backward">
                                <i class="fa-solid fa-backward"></i>
                            </button>
                            <button id="Forward">
                                <i class="fa-solid fa-forward"></i>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                
            </div>

        </div>

    </body>

</html>


The JS:

document.getElementById('Forward').addEventListener('click', () => {
        const currentPageNumber = getCurrentPageNumber();
        const nextPageNumber = currentPageNumber + 1;
        window.location.href = `/Pages/Inventory/${nextPageNumber}`;
    });
    
    document.getElementById('Backward').addEventListener('click', () => {
        const currentPageNumber = getCurrentPageNumber();
        if (currentPageNumber > 1) {
            const prevPageNumber = currentPageNumber - 1;
            window.location.href = `/Pages/Inventory/${prevPageNumber}`;
        }
    });
    
    function getCurrentPageNumber() {
        const currentPagePath = window.location.pathname;
        const pageNumber = currentPagePath.split('/').pop();
        return parseInt(pageNumber);
    }


When i first access the inventory i start at Pages/Inventory/1, and on the first page the pagination navigation works as intended as with the click of the button "forward" button i am able to access Pages/Inventory/2. But this is where the problem rears its head as the pagination controls seem to be frozen? The hover effects doesn't work on the forward and backward button and neither are they clickable and thus im unable to navigate forward to the third page or even return to the first page via these frozen controls.
Im not too sure what im getting wrong here but if you know the solution or the problem causing this please do lend a helping hand

Are you getting any errors in the browser console?

At the container of the buttons, is the data-pageNumber attribute used anywhere? Might cause an issue, since it's hardcoded to be 1.
